# Fail to write to /proc/<pid>/coredump_filter

Tags: c++, linux

My code(below) fails: 
11:Resource temporarily unavailable
The code is running as root (in an abrt hook) but has seteuid to the user that the pid in question is running as. 
Writing to /proc/self/coredump_filter from within the process works OK.
How can I write to the coredump_filter from the abrt hook?

```
void SetDumpFlags(pid_t pid, int dumpflags){
std::string c_filter_name = "/proc/" + std::to_string( pid ) + "/coredump_filter";
int f = open( c_filter_name.c_str(), O_WRONLY );
if (f < 0) {
    fprintf( log, "Couldn't open %s\n", c_filter_name.c_str());
    bail_out(1);
}
int wsz = write( f, &dumpflags, sizeof dumpflags);

if (wsz != sizeof dumpflags){
    fprintf( log, "Couldn't write to %s, %d:%s\n", c_filter_name.c_str(),errno, strerror(errno));
    close( f );
    bail_out(1);
}
close( f );
fprintf( log, "Pid %d, dump filter set to 0x%x\n", pid, dumpflags);
}
```

Comment: You realize that open fails with -1 not 0 and write doesn't do formatting, right?

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected those points (see editted code). It still fails with the same result.
I think the permissions are ok because I get a different result (the open fails) when I try to write the coredump_filter for a process running as another user.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your problem with a C example
(I would use C++11 but I'm on an ancient netbook without C++11 and it'd be hard to get it here and aclimate in the language).

I got an `EACCESS` on the `open` (and my guess you might be getting it too but the errno could get overwritten elsewhere?).

It seems the `coredump_filter` (at least on this Linux 3.2) starts as owned by
root and the `seteuid` doesn't change it.

I tried `chown` before `setuid` to no avail.

What did work (as expected) was to open the fd while you're still root
and keep it open during the seteuid call.
Then I could write to the file again successfully even after my euid changed.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FLAGS "0x11"
#define FLAGSSZ (sizeof(FLAGS)-1)
int main()
{
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    char buf[sizeof("/proc/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/coredump_filter")];
    sprintf(buf,"/proc/%ld/coredump_filter",(long)pid);
    int f;
    if(0>(f=open(buf,O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC))) {perror("open");exit(1);}
    if(FLAGSSZ != write(f,FLAGS,FLAGSSZ)){perror("write");exit(1);}
    puts("ok");

    char cat[sizeof("cat /proc/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/coredump_filter")];
    sprintf(cat,"cat /proc/%ld/coredump_filter", (long)pid);

    system(cat);

    char ls[sizeof("ls -l /proc/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/coredump_filter")];
    sprintf(ls,"ls -l /proc/%ld/coredump_filter", (long)pid);
    system(ls); //owned by root, not writable by others
    if(0>chown(buf,getuid(),getgid())){perror("chown"); exit(1); }
    //chown returns success but ls -l doesn't agree
    system(ls); //still owned by root

    if(0>seteuid(getuid())){
        perror("seteuid");
        exit(1);
    }
    //can't reopen because of the perms but can still
    //use the old fd if we kept it open
    if(0>lseek(f,SEEK_SET,0)){perror("lseek"); exit(1);}
    #define ALTFLAGS "0x22"
    #define ALTFLAGSSZ (sizeof(ALTFLAGS)-1)
    if(ALTFLAGSSZ != write(f,ALTFLAGS,ALTFLAGSSZ)){perror("write");exit(1);}
    puts("ok");
    system(cat);

}
```

I compiled with `gcc c.c` and made the a.out setuid root with `sudo sh -c 'chown 0 $1 && chmod u+s $1' - a.out` before running it.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to write data to the coredump_filter whereas I should have written a string! Doing it with a literal (e.g. #define FLAGS "0x11" as in the answer given by PSkocik ) fixes the problem.

The /proc/nnnnn/coredump_filter file is owned by the user that process nnnnn is running as. In my case this is root for some processes and another user for others. Switching user (in the abrt hook) to the appropriate user, before trying to write the coredump_filter, works OK.